JQuery .show() working, but .hide() not working
I am trying to build a dropdown select box in js, which I have to use js as it includes images. The problem is, when I click on the "input box" i made the jquery code to open it works i.e.
$('#ratingDropdownContainer').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#dropdownListContainer').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('#dropdownListContainer').show();
    }
})

and there is no problem. But when the user selects one of the options, the .hide() won't work. The in-line style of
style="display: block;"

doesn't change when I do
$('#dropdownListContainer').hide();
I have tried many things such as: making sure its wrapped in a $(document).ready(function(), checking if js recognizes its display is block (which it is as the console.log("okokoko"); prints as seen in my code below), I make sure my jquery is loaded before my js file, I tried using vanilla js instead, but none of those have worked, and I don't understand why the .show() would work but not the .hide(). Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.
js:
$('#ratingDropdownContainer').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.dropdown-list-container').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('.dropdown-list-container').show();
    }
})

$('.avg-rating-select').on('click', function() {
    var selectedRatingImg = $(this).find('img').prop('outerHTML');
    var selectedRatingText = $(this).find('p').prop('outerHTML');

    var newDiv = $("<div>" + selectedRatingImg + selectedRatingText + "</div>");
    newDiv.addClass("rating-selected-container");

    if ($('.rating-selected-container').length) {
        $('.rating-selected-container').replaceWith(newDiv);
    } else {
        $('.rating-dropdown-inner-text p').replaceWith(newDiv);
    }
    if ($('.dropdown-list-container').css('display') === 'block') {
        console.log("okokoko");
        $('.dropdown-list-container').hide();
    }
})

html:
<div class="col">
                          <div class="rating-dropdown-container" id="ratingDropdownContainer">
                            <div class="rating-dropdown-inner-text">
                              <p>Average Rating...</p>
                              <i class="bi bi-caret-down-fill"></i>
                            </div>
                          <div class="dropdown-list-container" id="dropdownListContainer">
                            <ul class="rating-dropdown">
                              <li class="avg-rating-select">
                                <img src="/media/main/5stars.png" alt="5stars" class="avg-rating-select-img">
                                <p class="avg-rating-select-text">5 Stars & Up</p>
                              </li>
                              <li class="avg-rating-select">
                                <img src="/media/main/4stars.png" alt="4stars" class="avg-rating-select-img">
                                <p class="avg-rating-select-text">4 Stars & Up</p>
                              </li>
                              <li class="avg-rating-select">
                                <img src="/media/main/3stars.png" alt="3stars" class="avg-rating-select-img">
                                <p class="avg-rating-select-text">3 Stars & Up</p>
                              </li>
                              <li class="avg-rating-select">
                                <img src="/media/main/2stars.png" alt="2stars" class="avg-rating-select-img">
                                <p class="avg-rating-select-text">2 Stars & Up</p>
                              </li>
                              <li class="avg-rating-select">
                                <img src="/media/main/1stars.png" alt="1stars" class="avg-rating-select-img">
                                <p class="avg-rating-select-text">1 Star & Up</p>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

css:
.rating-dropdown-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: .375rem;
  transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown-list-container {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-top:none;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: .375rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .375rem;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:-12px;
    background-color: #fff;
}


.avg-rating-select {
    padding-left: 8px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

(Note: this is a Django project that uses bootstrap if that helps)

The issue might be related to event propagation or event delegation. Try to stop the event propagation when clicking on the options inside the dropdown by event.stopPropagation() so:

$('#ratingDropdownContainer').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.dropdown-list-container').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('.dropdown-list-container').show();
    }
})

$('.avg-rating-select').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropogation(); // change here.
    var selectedRatingImg = $(this).find('img').prop('outerHTML');
    var selectedRatingText = $(this).find('p').prop('outerHTML');

    var newDiv = $("<div>" + selectedRatingImg + selectedRatingText + "</div>");
    newDiv.addClass("rating-selected-container");

    if ($('.rating-selected-container').length) {
        $('.rating-selected-container').replaceWith(newDiv);
    } else {
        $('.rating-dropdown-inner-text p').replaceWith(newDiv);
    }
    if ($('.dropdown-list-container').css('display') === 'block') {
        console.log("okokoko");
        $('.dropdown-list-container').hide();
    }
})

